# Setting up Android Billing Key- Ionic 4

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, ionic4, billing

I want to set up my Billing Key in my Ionic 4 Application.

I am using this cordova plugin for In App Purchases: https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

So I have done this, to set up the Billing Key:

[Setting up Billing Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiYgp.png)

If I run my App with `ionic cordova run android -l` everything works fine.

When I want to publish my app with `ionic cordova build android` the `www` folder with the `manifest.json` in the picture above gets cleared and InAppPurchases don't work anymore.

Is there another way to set up the Billing Key?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Devner did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @DuyAnh For now, I have shelved my work on this topic. I am working on the core of my project for now and will pursue research on this topic as and when I find some time. If I happen to stumble across any solution, I would gladly share with you.

Answer (score 0):

For who's that are facing this issue, the solution is a bit simple. Go to the `platform/android/project.properties` file and search and update the billing properties to: `cordova.system.library.1=com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.3`.

After that run: `ionic cordova prepare android`.